# Emacs Robe - Invalid Option -e (OptionParser)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, emacs

I need a help in order to debug this issue regarding start [Robe](https://github.com/dgutov/robe) on a 2.3.4 Rails project, when I try to start the robe (`robe-start`) I see:

```
/Users/edipo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4@project_name/gems/railties-3.2.22.5/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:23:in `block in start': invalid option: -e (OptionParser::InvalidOption)
```

Anyone already face this issue? Any help is welcome.

Comment: What is robe? It helps if you include links to the utilities you're using as part of a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

Rails 3 is not supported by `inf-ruby-console-rails`, sorry.

See the [minimal] discussion at https://github.com/nonsequitur/inf-ruby/pull/119.

And Robe uses the above command to launch the Rails console.

The alternatives to upgrading would be copying an old definition of that command to your init script, or evaluating `(inf-ruby-console-run "bundle exec rails console development" "rails")` manually every time to start that console before `M-x robe-start`.